# Time complexity for mod operation.

Tags: modular-arithmetic

> Let $x,y,n$ be $1234567809,12345,9087654321$.
>
> My laptop can perform $1$ $64$-bit integer mod operation in $1$ microsecond.
>
> Estimate the number of seconds needed for each of the following:
>
> 1. Find $x^y\pmod n$
> 2. Find $t$ such that $x^t=2672633475\pmod n$

I guess around $10^{45}$ digits, am I right and how do I calculate time from here?

Comment: You don't need to do any calculations with $10^{45}$-digit numbers. Do all the calculations mod $n$ and none of the results​ can exceed $n$.

Comment: @MJD: Well, intermediate results will usually do exceed $n$, for example when you use ordinary multiplicaton and mod like `a·b=(a*n) mod n`. You can of course implemend multiplication by hand and then intermediate results won't exceed $2n$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that the time needed to perform a 64bit multiplication is also 1 microsecond. Then $x^y \pmod n$ can be computed in $\log n$ operations of multiplying and dividing modulo with the help of exponentiation by squaring.

Second example: look at prime divisors of $n$. What can you say?

Answer (score 0):

ad 1: In base 2, $y$ reads:·
$$y=12345 = 11\,0000\,0011\,1001_2$$
i.e. in order to perform $x^y\bmod n$ you need

- $5=\operatorname{popcount}(y)-1\quad$ times (Mul + Mod)
- $13 = \operatorname{bitlen}(y) - 1\quad$ times (Square + Mod)

assuming you start expansion at the most significant bit of $y$. Hence the number of modular operations needed is:

$$18\times\text{Mul}+18\times\text{Mod}$$

under the assumption that squaring performs no better than multiplying. Notice however that $$n = 9\,087\,654\,321 \geqslant 2^{32}=4\,294\,967\,296$$

and therefore when you are multiplying two numbers in $[0,n)$, then the result will not fit in a 64-bit register in general. (Using signed residues in $[-n/2, n/2]$ won't help). Using 70-bit arithmetic would be sufficient though.

For part 2 of the question depends on what algorithm you are using.  You want to compute the [discrete logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm), which is costly.